# How to get name of each and every file in a folder and apply in a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, solr, filesystems

I want to create a Windows batch file that take each and every file with particular extn (say *.doc ) and apply in a command syntax and execute it. How to do this ?

for ex:

```
a folder contains
a.doc
b.doc
c.doc
```

format of command

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=**** -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar ****

where
**** -> name of each document
```

for ex at first iteration it should produce.

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=a.doc -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar a.doc
```

and have to execute it.

at 2nd iteration.

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=b.doc-Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar b.doc
```

like this.

How can I do this?

Note : the used file name should not repeat again (not used again in cmd production )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd c:\test_dir

for /r %%a in (*) do (

  java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=%%~nxa -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar "%%~dpfnxa"
)
```

This will process the files recursively.You can filter the files "wild-cards" expression ->
`for /r %%a in (*doc)` or do it only for the current folder `for %%a in (*)` .

Comment: Thanks.. But this produce the full path of the file on the %%~dpfnxa . So I modified the as http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id="%%~nxa" -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar "%%~nxa" .    Thanks for your answer @npocmaka